# Javascript to click and drag over elements

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, mouseevent

I'm using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to scrape and crawl around on sites and I've come to a page where, in order to book the time slots during a day for an event in a calendar, I have to click, hold down the mouse button and move the mouse over all the time slots I want to occupy during the event. The day is a table row and the slots are in table columns with randomly generated ids, like this;

```
<tr class="day" id="monday">
    <td class="slot" id="randomly-generated-id">Morning</td>
    <td class="slot" id="randomly-generated-id">Lunch</td>
    <td class="slot" id="randomly-generated-id">Afternoon</td>
    <td class="slot" id="randomly-generated-id">Night</td>
</tr>
```

I want to book the entire day for the event and in a normal, graphic browser this is done by clicking on the earliest slot and dragging the mouse over each slot that you want to book for this particular event. How would you trigger a command like that in javascript? jQuery could also work.

Answer (score 1):

I forked another persons solution and tweaked it to fit your needs but was only able to get the example to work with anything but tables (tr td), check it our here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dcantato/fzkgLq6h/

This accomplishes what you want and I personally prefer to work with divs over tables.
The main thing you will want to take away from this if you re-write your own function is

```
window.getSelection();
```

and

```
document.selection.createRange();
```

There is a few more complicated things going on in this well written code but from those building blocks you can rewrite it.

Comment: I'll try it out, but I can't help that the calendar is a table since I didn't write it. I'm just crawling around on it.

Comment: I had a hunch and updated the table, it appears it wasn't working initially because it was missing the table tag in the html. See the same fiddle updated.